# NextJS if router.back() has no history to route to, route to home

Tags: reactjs, next.js, browser-history, next-router

I'm using NextJS (v.13.4.15) app directory

I'm using a react-native webview to display a website inside of a mobile app, so a back button is critical for navigation (I cannot access the browser's back button)

I want something like

'use client' for client component:

```
    <button
      onClick={() => window.history.state && window.history.state.idx > 0 ? router.back() : router.push('/')}
    >
```

However I cannot get this to work, NextJS seems to have issues with accessing window.history (or maybe it's not NextJS and it's just a privacy thing)

And even if I can access the window, the window object contains confusing and inconsistent children properties and values like this:

```
{
    "__NA": true,
    "tree": [
        "",
        {
            "children": [
                "courses",
                {
                    "children": [
                        [
                            "slug",
                            "hacking-success",
                            "c"
                        ],
                        {
                            "children": [
                                "__PAGE__",
                                {}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        null,
        null,
        true
    ]
}
```

There has to be a way to check if (router.back()) is null or cannot go back, and then router.push('/) right?

ideally:

```
router.back() ?? router.push('/')
```

or can someone help explain this history.state.idx.tree? The length doesn't seem to match the number of history items from navigation, but rather the parent/hierarchy of the URL

I've wished that NextJS would have a method on the router that would return the history or provide a null/false value if the history is empty

However I've read the [useRouter() documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) and no method seems to exist

I've tried to access the `window.history` object but cannot write code to check if history does not contain a path to navigate back to

My only other idea is to pass a parameter when linking to a "non home page" that can be checked and then conditionally change the back button logic based on the parameter, but that seems inefficient

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725680/conditional-back-button-in-nextjs) is close but also seems inefficient