# How to go to previous page with Next js 13 navigation?

Tags: javascript, next.js13

What I want to do is navigate to the previous page using next/navigation when clicking on a link or  a button as such:

```
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function SupplierList() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => router.back()}>Back</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This doesn't work as next/navigation happens on server render but is inside a client component and gets a hydration error.

Does anyone have a good working example of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on stack overflow here:

[Conditional back button in nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725680/conditional-back-button-in-nextjs)

Where they use the useCallback hook to determine where to navigate the user. With this knowledge I have applied it to the button like this:

```
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function SupplierList() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    router.back();
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => onClick}>Back</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And it works successfully without a hydration error. I don't know yet why it works but I will go and read up on the useCallback function and see.

Comment: Will redirect user to another website in case they had entered your website URL while they were in another website in the address bar